# how to make a piece of code as an atomic operation in Linux-ARM

Tags: linux, arm, atomic

For example, I'd like my function `func1()` to be an atomic operation, that is no other thread or function will interrupt when `func1()` is running.

Is there a way to achieve that in the Linux environment on an ARM architecture?

thanks

Comment: In Linux user space the answer is **NO**.  There are *atomic* primitives that can be used for *lock free* data processing.  Also, you can use *mutexes* via *futexes*.  However, I think you need to give more details.  The ARM supports limited atomic instructions and depends on the CPU version.

Comment: where is this func1() running? In userspace/kernelspace? on behalf of userspace? if it is any of these except interrupt handler I dont think it can be possible. Because interrupts can any time come ans interrupt.

Comment: This can only be done in kernel space, or with real time extensions to linux.  In user space, the kernel is always allowed to interrupt you at any point it pleases.